# Selecting specific columns from a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
index  a   b   c
1      2   3   4
2      3   4   5
```

How do I slice out just columns 0 and 2 so it is:

```
index  a   c
1      2   4
2      3   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use `iloc`, using the `:` operator to select all rows, and a list of column numbers:

```
>>> df
       a  b  c
index         
1      2  3  4
2      3  4  5

>>> df.iloc[:,[0,2]]
       a  c
index      
1      2  4
2      3  5
```